# Different Aspect Ratio for Laptop + External Monitor

Tags: display-resolution

I'm looking at buying a Dell XPS which has a 16:10 aspect ratio for its screen.
My current monitors are 16:9.
Will Ubuntu be able to display both screens at once correctly if they require different aspect ratios?
I have 2 monitors so the laptop screen should be at 1920-1200 and the two monitors at 1920-1080
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for each monitor you can specify whatever supported resolution you require.